# s:select selected option from a list based on a condition

Tags: struts2

```
<s:select name='student' 
 list="students" listKey="sid" listValue="name"
 value="defaultStudent.equals('true')"
/>
```

I have a select tag as above. The Student object has a boolean value defaultStudent with getter isDefaultStudent. How to pre-select the default student based on this boolean value. Value accepts only static value not condition.

Comment: You can use OGNL. And it seems you're trying to compare boolean with a string.